# Google Sheets: is it possible to do an array function over for each element of another array?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I am trying to create a keyword generator in Google Sheets to dynamically generate them off of some input data and an array of legos that I am using a replace function to fill them in.  So far I am good on how to get that part working.  The issue comes in when I try to use a list of words to populate the strings.  I need it to generate the whole lego list for each word in the given array.
This works great for filling the list then adding some extra, predefined words to the end of the list:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(REPLACE(Legos, find("{1}",Legos),3, VLOOKUP("Service Name", Houdini,2,FALSE)));transpose(split(VLOOKUP("Other Words",Houdini,2),","))}
```

```
|Keywords|
|:-------|
|Best Houdini Render Farm|
|Cheap Houdini Renderfarm|
|Houdini renderfarm|
|Houdini farm|
|Mantra|
|Simulation|
```

but when I try to use the list of words on the legos, like so:

```
=arrayformula(REPLACE(Legos, find("{1}",Legos),3, transpose(split(VLOOKUP("Other Words",Houdini,2),","))))
```

```
|Keywords|
|:-------|
|Best Mantra Render Farm|
|Cheap Simulation Renderfarm|
|#N/A|
|#N/A|
```

What I am needing output is this:

```
|Keywords|
|:-------|
|Best Mantra Render Farm|
|Cheap Mantra Renderfarm|
|Mantra renderfarm|
|Mantra farm|
|Best Simulation Render Farm|
|Cheap Simulation Renderfarm|
|Simulation renderfarm|
|Simulation farm|
```

Comment: Here ya go
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZT_rYI_ERXAwXa626cVrq65Uoos-07QIM5RWjMXVHcQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide a more in depth explanation for what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @ale13 I essentially want to do a for each loop.  So for each member of this array, substitute the string into each member of another array.
If I were doing python it would be this:

output = []
for i in ListOfWords:
    a = [ j.format(i) for j in ListOfKeywordTemplates ]
    output = output + a
print(output)

Comment: @ale13 of course, \n is stripped from comments... that makes the code a whole lot less sensible. :(

Answer (score 0):

So I just went through and coded my own function to do it.  It was more straight forward than I thought it would be and just saved me the headache.

Here is the code just in case anyone wants to use it themselves:

```
function fillReplace(a, b) {
  output = []
  b.forEach(function(template) {
    sp = a.toString().split(",")
    sp.forEach(function(word){
      out = template.toString().replace("{1}",word.toString())
      output.push(out)
    })
  }) 
  return output
}
```

The templates take a form like "Best {1} Thing" and you give it a cell with a comma separated string to fill out all of the templates.